# Wrong Location - located in San Francisco and not in France

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I am in France, and when I try my new `func locationManager` function, my map view locate me in San Francisco. Any idea?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations[locations.count-1] as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

I am using the simulator.

Comment: Are you using the simulator or an actual iOS device?

Comment: I am using the simulator

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The iOS Simulator defaults to US - San Fran, and does not give you an estimate of your Mac's actual location.

However you can simulate movement or even a specific location like so:

Under the Debug menu **in the Simulator**, the last entry is "Location"; this gives you a sub menu with:

- None
- Custom Location
- Apple Stores
- Apple
- City Bicycle Ride
- City Run
- Freeway Drive
- Custom Location lets you enter a Lat/Long value.

Bicycle ride, City Run, and Freeway Drive are simulation of a moving location (in Cupertino, of course).

Comment: @PMIW absolutely no problem :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Woodstock's answer, you can also set a default location in the scheme. It's in Run/Options. There's an option to allow Location simulation and a bunch of standard defaults you can use for testing. For even more option, you can add a GPX file to your project.

Comment: Thank you for this precision :)
Where is "Run>Option" ?

Comment: Edit the scheme, pick Run from the column on the left, then the Options tab.

Comment: Thanks, I found an other way to do it ! Thanks again !